# GDB skip behaviour skipping over non selected files

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-code, gdb

I am using vscode and trying to debug a project with my problem being that I have to get into a copy constructor which is being called by a vector object when you add a new object to the vector. For many reasons I dont want to have to add a breakpoint to the clone constructor - and that means I have to step into std::vector until it calls the clone constructor. I used `skip -gfi ***/bits.*.h\` to skip over these files, except that means that I never get into the clone constructor function call - is there a way to overcome this, ie the debugger wont skip over the files it will just step into them until it gets back to the original project code? (I am hoping the IDE can have a workaround for this)

Comment: You have **many reason** why you don't want to add a breakpoint, could you at least tell us one?

Comment: Yea well it kind of breaks the point of debugging if it only shows part of the picture. What happened was that a bug was being caused by my constructor and I just didnt notice it bc I presumed the debugger would step into the function. But you are right that is unfortunate wording in the og post, mostly I just want to have everything setup perfectly in my IDE.

Comment: Now I understand your problem. I agree that this could be helpful in some cases, but I don't think this is possible right now.